# How to debug JavaScript with Firebug?

Tags: debugging, firebug

I cannot seem to debug my JavaScript code with Firebug. The play button is greyed out. I use FireFox 3.0.4 and Firebug 1.2.1.

Are there any known issues?

This is the script I want to debug:

(breakpoints set on `<img onclick>` and function `say()`), the code executes well.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.2.6"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function say(text){
                alert(text);
            }
        </script>
        <title>DOM Level 0 Event Handlers</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img onclick="say('Vroom vroom');" id="vstar" src="vstar.jpg" alt="vstar" />
        <div id="console"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I`ve never found a way to debug JS code that`s embedded within a non .js file (JSP, HTML, etc.), so I`d be very keen to hear any solution to this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check if you have "support for script debugging" enabled in Console. Its disabled by default for performance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I usually see this behavior if I forget to set a break point, or I have set the break points in places that don't get executed (so execution never stops, so the play button would never do anything).

Comment: Even a simple alert('Hallo'), whisch is executed, and breakpoint set, the buttons are greyed out and no debugging

Answer (score 0):

You need to close all instances of firefox and reopen. Firefox has shared memory, so you cannot open a new page.